# Laravel Blade View output loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have done the following query in Laravel 4 and I need to know how to output the results as a list for each value. Here is the query and and its result.

```
//List all the buyers
    $buyers = DB::table('requests')->get();



    $data = array();
        //Buyers Object 
            $data['requests']= $buyers;

return View::make('buyers.index',compact($data));
```

This was result.

```
  {"requests":[

{"id":1,"person":1000,"shoe":"nike","shoes":5,"money":250,"pay method":"paypal","Text":"blobs osf text","good":1:},

 {"id":2,"person":1002,"shoe":"adidas","shoesy":1,"money":100,"pay method":"moneytransfer","Text":"looking to pick up some BIT. Hit me up and  trade with me I am pretty competitive. We can work out something so we both get profits. one.","good":1}

]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use blade templates (http://laravel.com/docs/templates)

```
@foreach ($requests as $request)

    <h2>Request {{ $request['id'] }}</h2>

    <ul>
        @foreach ($request as $field => $value)
            <li>{{ $field }}:  {{ $value }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH :). Appreciate the solution and the tip.